# 2.8" TFT Touchscreen Prohibits Access to Unused Pins

Tags: arduino-uno

This is probably a beginner question. You've been warned.

I recently purchased a touchscreen (http://www.adafruit.com/products/1651#tutorials) specifically because it left so many pins open to work with and I needed to hook up one, possibly two more items to my Arduino. However the touchscreen fits over the Arduino and covers all the pins.

**How do I access the pins that the LCD isn't using?**

To be specific, I will be adding a Galvanic Skin Sensor on two analog pins.

Comment: The standard shield to processor extender pins/sokets are made to solder through a shield, with pins extending down into processor sockets and socket end up for a shield above. If you plug unsoldered ones of these onto the shield pins that are used by the LCD and plug them into the processor, the other processor pins will be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dupont jumper cables are your friend. The most useful ones are male-to-female:

[image]

You can end up with a bit of a tangled mess though when you have a number of shields all side by side.  Not a lot you can do about it though.

Answer (score 3):

Several options:

1. Use wires to connect it rather than sticking it directly onto the Arduino.
2. Use a header extension to lift the display away from the other headers.
3. Use right-angle headers on the other pins.

Comment: Would right-angle headers even be applicable in this situation? I'm not soldering anything. Thanks.

Comment: Just press-fit them into the existing headers.

Answer (score 0):

Really I'm just posting to have participated in the forum. Actually I'm new to arduino, and don't even know how many pins the screen actually uses. My version of the screen is a Pixnor screen made by someone who does not really provide technical description, examples, etc.,, and some of the pins are different, or perhaps the entire chip driving the shield is different, so none of the adafruit sketches work. I haven't figured out anything more than how to hook up the touch to an x,y coordinate serial read,, there's an example somewhere that leaves all of the pins unplugged, with the exception of the touchpad data wires, and lets you play on a dark screen with the coordinate plane.

but anyway, my first thought was, really the touchscreen should plug into a protoshield, which would allow you to have a pin-layout which runs to a protoshield, and then your screen would be fixed over that layout, when would then plop onto your arduino, or back off again without disassembling your sensor/input layout. (which means you can still rig up some experiment with the arduino without having to rerig up your screen and sensors.) ,, So I think I'm going to go about getting more proto-shields.

Answer (score -1):

get a Protoshield, a good one and put it between the arduino and the shield
[image: Proto shield that will work]

Comment: Please can you format/edit your images, and expand upon your answer and explain why a Protoshield would help?